# Div displayed as table has no limits

Tags: html, css

I've got this structure:

```
<div id="preview">
    <div class="small">preview</div>
    <div id="prev_content"></div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS rules:

```
#preview {
    position:absolute;
    display: table;
    top:160px;
    left:10px;
    width:457px;
    height:125px;
    max-width: 457px;
    max-height: 125px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-image:url(../images/preview_greetings.png);
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: shofar;
    font-size:27px;
    padding-right:130px;
    padding-left:20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#preview div.small{
    position: absolute;
    top:-40px;
    left:0px;
    text-align: center;
    width:607px;
    color:black;
    font-size:30px;
}

#prev_content{
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 102px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

but for some reason, if I have overflow text, it just keeps expanding the div and doesn't stop.

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sTGpf/

How can I make it stop growing when it has reached it's limitation? The reason im using table display is because I need vertical alignment.

Comment: put position: absolute; in your prev_content css.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sTGpf/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

display:table-cell is causing the height to expand based on content. Use a wrapper around the div and set the required style for vertical alignment. And for the DIV with actual content, set the max-height:102px;

```
#prev_content{
max-width: 100%;
max-height:102px;
}

#wrapper
{
vertical-align:middle;
display:table-cell;
max-height:102px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sTGpf/5/)

Comment: I realized that after posting the answer. Please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `display: table` to center, you could use [Centering in the Unknown](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/).

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sTGpf/8/)

```
#preview {
    height:125px;   
    font-size:0; /* To avoid extra spaces */
}
#preview:before {
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
}
#preview:before, #prev_content {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle
}
#prev_content{
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 102px;
    font-size: 27px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display: table-cell;` from #prev_content and it will respect the `max-height: 102px;`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sTGpf/3/

Comment: but I also need it vertically aligned. do you have any other ways to vertically align it then?

Comment: Vertical alignment also works for `display:inline-block` elements, which you can use to line up multiple elements next to one another.

Comment: Add line-height, e.g.  `line-height:125px;` to make vertical alight work

Comment: @SquareCat when I change it to `display:inline-block` the property `vertical-align` doesn't work. How can vertical alignment work with `display:inline-block`?